# Puzzle Solving: Finding All Words Within a Larger Word in PHP

Tags: php, string, cpu-word, puzzle, scramble

So I have a database of words between 3 and 20 characters long. I want to code something in PHP that finds all of the smaller words that are contained within a larger word. For example, in the word "inward" there are the words "rain", "win", "rid", etc.

At first I thought about adding a field to the Words tables (Words3 through Words20, denoting the number of letters in the words), something like "LetterCount"... for example, "rally" would be represented as 10000000000200000100000010: 1 instances of the letter A, 0 instances of the letter B, ... 2 instances of the letter L, etc. Then, go through all the words in each table (or one table if the target length of found words was specified) and compare the LetterCount of each word to the LetterCount of the source word ("inward" in the example above).

But then I started thinking that that would place too much of a load on the MySQL database as well as the PHP script, calling each and every word's LetterCount, comparing each and every digit to that of the source word, etc.

Is there an easier, perhaps more intuitive way of doing this? I'm open to using stored procedures if it will help with overhead in any way. Just some suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that should be pretty efficient, but will only work up to certain size of words (probably about 15-20 characters it will break down, depending on whether the letters making up the word are low-frequency letters with lower values or high-frequency letters with higher values):

1. Assign each letter a prime number according to it's frequency.  So `e` is 2, `t` = 3, `a` = 5, etc. using frequency values from [here](http://pages.central.edu/emp/lintont/classes/spring01/cryptography/letterfreq.html) or some similar source.
2. Precalculate the value of each word in your word list by multiplying the prime values for the letters in the word, and store in the table in a `bigint` data type column.  For instance, `tea` would have a value of `3*2*5=30`.  If a word has repeated letters, repeat the factor, so that `teat` should have a value of `3*2*5*3=90`.
3. When checking if a word, such as `rain`, is contained inside of another word, such as `inward`, it's sufficient to check if the value for `rain` divides the value for `inward`.  In this case, `inward = 14213045`, `rain = 7315`, and `14213045` is divisible by `7315`, so the word `rain` is inside the word `inward`.
4. A bigint column maxes out at `9223372036854775807`, which should be fine up to about 15-20 characters (depending on the frequencies of letters in the word).  For instance, I picked up the first 20-letter word from [here](http://www.wordbyletter.com/words_starting_with.php?q=a&letters=20), which is `anitinstitutionalism`, and has a value of `6901041299724096525` which would just barely fit inside the bigint column.  However, the 14-letter word `xylopyrography` has a value of `635285791503081662905`, which is too big.  You might have to handle the really large ones as special cases using an alternate method, but hopefully there's few enough of them that it would still be relatively efficient.

The query would work something like the demo I've prepared here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bd27/8

Comment: This is brilliant! I suppose I could test out a few of the 20-letter words in my database and figure out what their average prime-product would be. But this looks like a great way to go about doing this.

Comment: One way to scale this up to the 20 letters might be to split the word values into two parts, one for the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th letter etc, i.e., `e, a, n, s, ...` and one for the 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th letter etc, i.e., `t, i, o, r, ...`.  Then you would check if `value1` of the master word is divisible by `value1` of a word in the list, and also `value2` of the master word is divisible by `value2` of a word in the list.  The idea is the same, except with split into two numbers it's far more likely that all of your words will fit within the bigint range.

Comment: In the case of `xylopyrography`, this method would produce the more manageable values of `value1=1030010495` and `value2=10453831141`.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. So "inward" would be split to value1 = i, w, r and value2 = n, a, d? Or do you mean to separate the list of prime numbers (and their letters), and do it that way?

Comment: Yes separate the list of letters/prime numbers, otherwise you won't have standard values that you can divide.  Each value has to represent the same possible letters across the board or the division won't work properly.  Basically, the interleaving of 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc. that I described above helps balance the two values so they will both be generally smaller and roughly equal.

Comment: Exactly.  Did you get the same results? :)

Comment: No. For `xylopyrography` I get `641077061` and `1863896549`. But I guess it doesn't matter, as long as the methodology is the same when getting the values for the master word or the search words.

Comment: Ya, it's roughly the same. I had done it by hand in an Excel spreadsheet, so it's likely I made a mistake or three.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work though. Case in point: the word `gyro` gives `59` and `15067`. `Gyro` is inside `xylopyrography`, but `59` is not divisible into `641077061`, nor is `15067` divisible into `1863896549`.

Comment: It looks like `641077061` is prime.  I think you had an overflow in PHP while calculating the values for `xylopyrography`.  The values I got are divisible, `1030010495/59=17457805`, and `10453831141/15067=693823`.

Comment: Ah hah, yeah, using `sprintf` the way I did was apparently cutting off the last few digits of each number. Now I got it right. :) http://codepad.org/mWJmf1r6

Comment: You hadn't given me a chance to finish yet, but here's a MySQL solution: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa44c/5.  Hopefully it doesn't overflow or generate rounding errors with the `product()` calculation hack via `exp(sum(..))`.  It seems to work for all the test values I use, including `xylopyrography`, which agrees exactly with the values you produced.

Comment: In any case, populating the master values is a one-time operation so whatever method you can get to work is good.  From there, I'd be interested in the performance of a couple of real words with the complete dictionary.

Comment: Just loaded a ~130,000 word list into SQL Server with `BULK IMPORT` and ran the update statement, took about 1 minute total.  I can query for all the words inside of, say, `underneath`, and it returns `389` results in less than a second.  Wahoo!  The word in my database with the highest value for `value1` is `subshrubby: 345658978388237,19`.  The word with the highest value for `value2` is `micrococci:1,12679780555897`.  Looks like both values easily fit in the range for a `bigint` value in MySQL.  Hmm, looks like the word list I downloaded is 10-letter words max, so not a great test.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10016/discussion-between-terranrich-and-mellamokb)